# Are questions about microcontrollers off topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

Should we see questions about microcontrollers as inherently off topic or should we allow them? What do you all think?

Comment: For me, it depends.  Arduino has its own site, Raspberry Pi has its own site, Phones have their own sit. Anything fitting above will be off topic here.

Answer (score 4):

It isn't on topic here *except* in the narrow aspect of where there's issues where a computer interfaces with the microcontroller, for example when programming it.

There may be more specialised sites like arduino or EE.SE that might be better fits.

Comment: Is there any documentation at all to support that claim? It isn't on https://superuser.com/help/on-topic for example.

Comment: "*electronic devices*, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer,"

Comment: That is not saying microcontrollers are off topic. A computer is an "electronic device". It's pretty clear that the examples given, media players, cell phones, is just to make it clear that any arbitrary electronic device is not on topic. No engineer would call a microcontroller not a computer.

Comment: @BipedalJoe - You can’t possibly believe or expect every possible example be stated in the list of examples topics that are out of scope. Stack Exchange has likely two communities where question about microcontroller could possibly would be within scope. Electronic devices in this context does NOT include personal computers, throughput the help center, traditional (desktop, laptop, tablet) devices are called out. Likewise, phones which are also electronic devices, are specifically called out. Our specific expertise does not have to include microcontrollers